# Using ui-router with Kendo TabStrip

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, kendo-tabstrip

I am trying to implement a Kendo Tab Strip and that applies ui-router to display the contents of the tab.  I can get the tab strip to display but not the contents using the ui-view.  Anyone have an example of how to make these items work together.

Sample of my html.

```
<div class="main-template">
    <div class="row">
        <h3>Welcome to the Dashboard</h3>
        <div ng-controller="Navigation">
            <div kendo-tab-strip k-content-urls="[ null, null]">
                <!-- tab list -->
                <ul>
                    <li class="k-state-active" url="#/invoice">Invoice Management</li>
                    <li url="#/shipment">Shipment Management</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not merging everything together as I should.  In the li markup I should have used ui-sref instead of url.

```
<div class="main-template" style="margin-left: 10px;">
    <div class="row">
        <h3>Welcome to the Dashboard</h3>
        <!--<a ui-sref="invoice">Invoice</a>
        <div ui-view></div>-->
        <div ng-controller="Navigation">
            <div kendo-tab-strip="tabs">
                <!-- tab list -->
                <ul>
                    <li class="k-state-active" ui-sref="invoice">Invoice Management</li>
                    <li ui-sref="shipment">Shipment Management</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div ui-view></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```